# Can I use travis-ci to test against specific (including minor number) version of python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, continuous-integration, travis-ci

If you have this in your `.travis.yml` file:

```
language: python
python:
- 2.7
```

Your code will be tested against python 2.7.9:

```
$ source ~/virtualenv/python2.7/bin/activate
$ python --version
Python 2.7.9
```

But Python 2.7.9 breaks urllib3 (https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/issues/482) and gevent (https://github.com/gevent/gevent/issues/477). I guess this is why the latest Ubuntu still ships with Python 2.7.6.

For these reasons I really need to test my library against python >=2.7 but <2.7.9, is it possible to somehow specify minor python version in `.travis.yml`? I've tried:

```
python:
- 2.7.6
```

but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: It seems someone else required this version, and the devs were kind enough to [build 2.7.6 archives for them](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5078#issuecomment-156302257), so you may want to try again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot specify minor versions with Travis. But what you could do instead is using [Anaconda](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) with the conda environment. Thereby, you can install a *local* version of python of your choice.

In your `before_install` script you can download and set it up via:

```
  - wget http://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda-3.7.3-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh
  - bash miniconda.sh -b -p $HOME/miniconda
  - export PATH="$HOME/miniconda/bin:$PATH"
  - conda config --set always_yes yes --set changeps1 no
  - conda update -q conda
  # Useful for debugging any issues with conda
  - conda info -a
  # USE YOUR PYTHON VERSION HERE
  - conda create -q -n py276 python=2.7.6 
  - source activate py276
```

The important part here is, of course: `conda create -q -n py276 python=2.7.6`.

Thus, calls to `python` in your Travis script will automatically use the one installed with anaconda, i.e. Python 2.7.6.